# SenSentiStrength specific approach in R

Tags: r, nlp, quanteda

I try use [SentiStrength-SE](http://cs.uno.edu/~zibran/resources/MyPapers/1544a203.pdf) in r.

I have used lexicon using quanteda

Is there any option to use SentiStrength-SE?

Here an example input I try to implement:

```
dframe <- data.frame(text = c("I like this code option", "No this bug is not related to the system"))
```